# std::experimental in production code in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++-experimental

What is the current status of using std::experimental namespace in production? We are using Visual C++ to design some C++ UWP Windows Runtime Components. Right now when we write async code we use create_async, create_task, ... It would be more elegant to use coroutines. But since they are in std::experimental namespace we are not sure if the code is so mature to be used in production code?